# How do I build a Qt application without an X server requirement on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, xserver

I am trying to build a Piet IDE, but I am unable to figure out how to do so without the program giving an error saying `cannot connect to x server`.

It is called PietCreator, and can be found [here](https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator).

The pre-built binary can be found [here](https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator/downloads).

Thar binary doesn't require an X server, but for some reason the author didn't compile in GIF support. So I compiled it myself, with all the required dependencies, but when I build it it requires an X server. So when I start up Cygwin-X and run it through its terminal, and it starts, but the application has a lot of bugs not present in the pre-built binary.

I tried searching for how to build a Qt application without it requiring an X server, but I couldn't find anything. Can anyone offer any help? Thanks.

Comment: If you use the default Windows packages of Qt, no X server will be required.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld You mean the VS 2010 package, as opposed to MinGW or the one available through the Cygwin setup?

Comment: Sean Heiss: MSVC or standalone mingw, but not cygwin.